# I wish to add one more extra positional argument in all of my worksheet. write() and worksheet. write _datetime() methods

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, datetime, xlsxwriter

Basically I want to add variables that I created :

1. header_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'border': True, 'bg_color': 'yellow'})
2. body_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'border': True})

in this order ( full code ) :

```
def export_callcenter_26older_not_bg(self, file_name, sheet_name):

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_name + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)

    header, rows = DataForExport().callcenter_26older_not_bg()

    header_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'border': True, 'bg_color': 'yellow'})
    body_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'border': True})

    last = len(header)
    column_width = worksheet.set_column(1, last, 11)

    row_index = 0
    column_index = 0
    for column_name in header:
        worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column_name, column_width, header_cell_format )
        column_index += 1

    date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})

    for row_index, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(row):
            if isinstance(column, datetime.date):
                worksheet.write_datetime(row_index, column_index, column, date_format, body_cell_format)
            else:
                worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column, body_cell_format)

    print(f'{len(rows)} rows written successfully to {workbook.filename}')


    # Closing workbook
    workbook.close()
```

But I keep getting ERRORS that I have more then 4 positional arguments inside methods that are in for loops :

1. worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column_name, column_width, header_cell_format )
2. worksheet.write_datetime(row_index, column_index, column, date_format, body_cell_format)

How I can add extra positional arguments inside those methods ?
Thank you .

Comment: Are you hoping to combine the 2 formats you are trying to add to the `write*()` methods? If so that won't work. You will need to create a third format with the combined properties of the other 2 and add that instead.

Comment: Sry this might be a stupid question, but Im begginer...
I dont want to combine...
Basically because I have one extra argument in first worksheet. write () and one extra in  worksheet. write_ datetime () , just like Ive posted in my code section ( that code doesnt work btw since I have 5 out of 4 args which method accept )

Can you paste my code and modify it to work correct and post it here ? Thank you.

Comment: I can't post a solution because I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain that a bit better. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the first loop if you remove from the worksheet.write() method : arg. " header_cell_format " and in the second for loop if you remove from worksheet.write_datetime() method : arg. " body_cell_format " the code will work and you will get table without formatted table frames. How I cant achieve to format the table using the variables in which I specified the formats, how to implement them in the existing for loops that define the names of the columns and the data in the rows ?

Comment: In the first loop you need to remove `column_width` from the arguments. In the second loop you need to remove either `date_format` or `body_cell_format`.  You can’t have both. If you want to add a format that has both sets of properties (in the second loop) you need to create a new format the has both sets of properties. Like: `body_date_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'border': True, 'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})`.

Comment: @jmcnamara God bless you ! Thank you very much for your help !
Found the solution for first for loop actually how to be able to run both 
objects column_width and header_cell_format is to define for loop like this :

row_index = 0
        column_index = 0
        for column_name in header:
            worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column_name, column_width)
            worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column_name, header_cell_format)
            column_index += 1

# you really helped me a lot and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
    def export_callcenter_26older_not_bg(self, file_name, sheet_name):

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_name + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)

    header, rows = DataForExport().callcenter_26older_not_bg()

    last = len(header)
    column_width = worksheet.set_column(0, last, 11)
    header_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'border': True, 'bg_color': 'yellow'})

    row_index = 0
    column_index = 0
    for column_name in header:
        worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column_name, column_width)
        worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column_name, header_cell_format)
        column_index += 1

    date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})
    body_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'border': True})
    body_date_cell_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'border': True})

    for row_index, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        for column_index, column in enumerate(row):
            if isinstance(column, datetime.date):
                worksheet.write_datetime(row_index, column_index, column, body_date_cell_format)
            else:
                worksheet.write(row_index, column_index, column, body_cell_format)


    print(f'{len(rows)} rows written successfully to {workbook.filename}')

    # Closing workbook
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).